# "Was a moment that wasn't"

Tags: meaning

The headline of a CNN news of August 11 reads, "In Trump's White House, Charlottesville was a moment that wasn't."

What does "Charlottesville was a moment that wasn't" mean?

Comment: [The relevant article](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/08/11/politics/donald-trump-charlottesville-one-year-later/index.html) seems to be saying that *when President Donald Trump declared a year ago that "very fine people" were among the Nazi mobs descending upon Charlottesville*, this was so obviously "shocking" that all the White House staff would be bound to resign and force a premature end to Trump's presidency. Which is to say it was supposed to be a "defining moment". Except that everyone *didn't* resign, and Trump is still in post, apparently undamaged by it all.

Comment: Isn't this a case of *to be* used without any complement, meaning "to exist", i.e. "Charlottesville was a moment that [in the minds of those in the White House] didn't exist"?

Answer (score 1):

They are doing a play on words with:

> Charlottesville **was** a moment that **wasn't**.

Normally the [predicate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/predicate) (the part after *Charlottesville was*) would further define what the event at Charlottesville **was** (is), for example: *Charlottesville was a moment of reflection on the obesity epidemic in the USA*.

Here, [CNN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1IDF-8khS3w) further defines the subject by negating it and saying that *"In Trump's White House (WH),"* the event that happened at Charlottesville *was not an event*, that is to say, (CNN claims that) they (WH) does not acknowledge, notice, or otherwise give any attention to that event. So, to the WH, **it wasn't an event (or moment)**; thus:

> "In Trump's WH, Charelottesville was a moment that was not."

Answer (score 0):

“Was a moment that wasn't” from:

**not for a moment** the idiom. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+for+a+moment)

> Not for any length of time; not at any point; not at all or in any
>   capacity.

As in:

From the media's point of view:

"In Trump's White House, Charlottesville, a momentous event was ... shrugged off!"

From Trump et. al.:

"The White House has dealt with Charlottesville, and we shall move on!"